# C# Windows event log custom data

Tags: c#, .net, xml, event-log

I would like to add custom data into the Windows event log message as formatted text (XML string) . Whatever I add, gets added as strings and are shown with the XML tags. Is there a recommended way to add custom data to the log entry? A typical log entry looks like this:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
        ...
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data>3031358440</Data> 
  <Data>5</Data> 
  <Data>WindowsUpdateFailure</Data> 
  <Data>Not available</Data> 
 </EventData>
</Event>
```

I would like to add data like this:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
        ...
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data>
    <ThreadID/>
    <AssignedPriority/>
  </Data>
 </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: For anyone who is interested, I ended up using key=value pairs in the description.

Comment: If you have found a solution, please post it as an answer. This will help future users find the answer easier, and you can earn more upvotes/reputation.